# Retrieve a range of records from SQL query Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have this Java code which is used for JSF pagination:

```
public List<ActiveSessionObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws Exception {

        String SQL_LIST_BY_ORDER_AND_LIMIT = "SELECT * FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?, ?";



        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        String sql = String.format(SQL_LIST_BY_ORDER_AND_LIMIT, sortField, sortDirection);
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList = new ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj>();

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, sortField);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, sortDirection);
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, firstRow);
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, rowCount);

            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            /* take the result from the SQL query and insert it into Array List collection */
            dataList = ActiveSessionsArrayList(resultSet);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }

        return dataList;
    }
```

I use this SQL statement to generate ArrayList:

```
SELECT * FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?, ?
```

Can this SQL query be used for Oracle? Or this is MySQL specific?

Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Case1: If you want first `twenty Records` only then 

 select * from ( 
     select rn,a.*
     from Activesessionlogs a
     order by ??)
 where rn <=20
 order by rn

Case2:If you want the record between `5 to 10` then

select * from (
select rownum rn,e.* from Activesessionlogs e order by ??)
where rn >=5 and rn<=10 
order by rn
```

**Eg:**
     Lets find an example below

```
select * from (
select rownum rn,e.* from emp e order by hiredate)
where rn >=5 and rn<=10
order by rn asc
```

[image: output]

**Note** :`Rownum> or rownum>=` will not work in the same query .A very good blog explaining this [Oracle Rownum](http://blog.lishman.com/2008/03/rownum.html)

Comment: The first example (Case1) will **not** work. You cannot combine rownum and an order by at the same level in the statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:sir it is working for me ,in case 1 when i do order by hiredate,if you want i will present you with an example

Comment: The results will **not** be consistent because the rownum value is assigned *before* any ordering is done. See my example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bede9/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:yes you're right ,thanks for this ,i will change my solution

Answer (score 3):

`LIMIT` is MySQL specific. However in Oracle you can use `rownum` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT columnA, columnB, rownum as my_rownum
FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG
ORDER BY ? ?) 
WHERE my_rownum <= ? 
AND my_rownum >= ?
```

Comment: Correct, I forgot to put the rownum in the subquery, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LIMIT is not a valid statement in oracle, it is used in MySql. However oracle has a variable ROWNUM which you can use to limit the number of rows returned:

```
select * from mytable where rownum <= 100 and rownum > 50
```

returns the second 50 records from your query.